# How to capture the output of a bash command which prompts for a user's confirmation without blocking the output nor the command

Tags: bash, command, output, nonblocking, capture

I need to capture the output of a bash command which prompts for a user's confirmation without altering its flow.

I know only 2 ways to capture a command output:

```
- output=$(command)
- command > file
```

In both cases, the whole process is blocked without any output.

For instance, without --assume-yes:

```
output=$(apt purge 2>&1 some_package)
```

I cannot print the output back because the command is not done yet.

Any suggestion?

Edit 1: The user must be able to answer the prompt.

EDIT 2: I used dash-o's answer to complete a [bash script](https://git.sdxlive.com/DR/#removing-obsolete-packages) allowing a user to remove/purge all obsolete packages (which have no installation candidate) from any Debian/Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: Are you looking to capture (partial) output at the point when the command prompts the user for confirmation ? The second form 'command > file' will store partial output (if any) to the file. Usually, prompts will occur before any action is performed/output is generated

Comment: Yes, that's the intended goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture partial output from that is waiting for a prompt, one can use a tail on temporary file, potentiality with 'tee' to keep the output flowing if needed. The downside of this approach is that stderr need to be tied with stdout, making it hard to tell between the two (if this is an issue)

```
#! /bin/bash

log=/path/to/log-file
echo > $log
(
  while ! grep -q -F 'continue?' $log ; do sleep 2 ; done ; 
  output=$(<$log) 
  echo do-something "$output"
) &
# Run command with output to terminal
apt purge 2>&1 some_package | tee -a $log

# If output to terminal not needed, replace above command with
apt purge 2>&1 some_package > $log
```

There is no generic way to tell (from a script) when exactly a program prompts for input. The above code looks for the prompt string ('continue?'), so this will have to be customized per command.

Comment: **Perfect!** But I cannot manage to filter out some lines from the output. 1) `apt purge 2>&1 some_package | tee -a $log | grep -v "apt does not have a stable CLI interface"` removes the prompt line `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]` before it is answered. 2) `apt purge 2>&1 some_package | grep -v "apt does not have a stable CLI interface" | tee -a $log` removes all output before it is answered. 3) Inserting `sed -i '/apt does not have a stable CLI interface/d' $log` (for instance) after the while loop does not affect what is displayed on the terminal.